# Shared storage between Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, high-availability, file-permissions, shared-storage

We're planning to set up HA apache servers in our virtual environment. The load balancing between the servers is working fine. The problem we face is the following:

We'd like to have one physical storage for all of the apache servers (Thats where the webcontent will be placed). Every customer gets his own user and his own directory on the storage disk. That means every customer should only be able to access his own directory on this "shared" storage from each of our apache servers.

What is the best way to achieve our goal in terms of:

- Synced users
- Shared storage
- Synced permissions
- High availability
- High performance

Comment: Probably distributed FS like Gluster or Ceph. For shared system users you can use NIS (the easiest implementation) or more robust things like LDAP or IPA.

Comment: Or buy a NAS of some form

Comment: OCFS is a good alternative too.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you look at Starwind VSA or Ceph? With Ceph you will achieve in free open source solution, but you need skills to configure and support it by yourself. AFAIR, Starwind VSA based on a Linux is a free too, but you can always double check it with their engineers.http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/architecture/
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-vsa